# 504 ошибка при отправке любого сообщения через smtp.yandex.ru на laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Laravel Framework 9.27.0
php v8.1.11

В .env все настроено правильно, такие же настройки (логины пароли) работают на другом проекте, а на новом происходит долгая загрузка и 504 ошибка

В логах выводит:

```
production.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465 (Connection timed out) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mailer\\Exception\\TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host \"ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465\": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465 (Connection timed out) at /var/www/html/flower/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/Stream/SocketStream.php:154)
```

Comment: Сервер один и тот же, у старого и нового проекта?

Comment: нет, они разные

Comment: Пишите в поддержку хостера, некоторые блокируют smtp

Comment: действительно, спасибо